# Консоль разработчика в онлайн игре

Tags: c#, unity3d

Есть авторитарный сервер и клиент на юнити. Хотелось бы сделать в клиенте терминал (на "~", к примеру), в котором можно вводить чит коды, такие как: add_gold  , add_hp  . Суть в том, что бы эти команды парсились в клиенте и отправлялись серверу на выполнение. Как делать защиту, что бы посторонние не взломали клиент и не получили доступ к консоли? Делать в виде библиотеки, которая будет исключена после сборки или есть другие варианты? Как лучше подобную вещь реализовать?

Comment: Проверка на client-side - очень плохая затея. Лучше реализовать на сервере проверку, имеет ли пользователь права на использование тех или иных команд.

Comment: Если вам это только в редакторе нужно - можете сделать либу, а можете обернуть всё в дефайн #UNITY_EDITOR, если и в билдах, то только проверка прав пользователя на сервере.

Comment: Не нужно бояться, что обычный юзер призовёт консоль. Защищать клиент это глупость, защищаем только сервер от клиента. Поэтому любой не пользовательский запрос с клиента проверяется на права модератора этой учётки, что и будет проверять какой-нибудь php скрипт на сервере, сверяясь с базой и отправляя некий error в консоль типа "Хрен тебе а не add_gold" безправным или success.

Comment: На тему взлома... опытному человеку даже не нужен клиент, его цель узнать адреса и запросы.

Comment: У меня был такой вариант изначально, делать на сервере проверку на права пользователя (админ, тестер). Думал, может есть альтернативные варианты, без привязки по правам, а по секретному сложному паролю или с определенного IP адреса.

Comment: Вариант есть. Ради бога. Вопрос только в том насколько он безопасней. В Fallout 76 множество ужасных и не безопасных вариантов, которые находили (включая пароль от терминала модерской комнаты). Cкомпрометировать проверку на сервере можно лишь имея полный доступ и заменив скрипт проверки, но тогда проще напрямую отредактировать данные в таблицах баз данных.